# Как запросить у пользователя выбор приложения по умолчанию и узнать какое он выбрал?

Tags: java, android

Нужно, чтобы допустим при при клике на кнопку открывалось окно с выбором приложения по умолчанию. К примеру, как на скрине №3.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
После того как приложение по умолчанию будет выбрано пользователем, нужно, как-то проверять какое приложение им было выбрано и если было выбрано не наше приложение - определять это.

*P.S. В моём случае нужно, чтобы пользователь выбрал приложение по умолчанию для смс.*

Как этого добиться?
Пожалуйста, приведите пример кода.

Comment: я еще интент нашел интересный на ту же тему, добавил ссылку в ответ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы определить выбранное пользователем приложение по умолчанию, вам должен помочь метод [PackageManager.resolveActivity()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#resolveActivity(android.content.Intent,%20int))

Начиная с API 24 приложение может получить интент [ACTION_DEFAULT_SMS_PACKAGE_CHANGED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.Sms.Intents.html#ACTION_DEFAULT_SMS_PACKAGE_CHANGED) о том, что оно стало или перестало быть дефолтным приложением для получения SMS.